# :first-child CSS Selector not targeting correct element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My website has the following HTML

```
<article>
    <p>Header</p>
    <p>Some content</p>
</article>
```

I would like the 'header' to be bold. I've followed the example on W3Schools, in regards to CSS selectors which states

> :first-child - Selects every `<p>` element that is the first child of its parent

My CSS is

```
article:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

the problem is, my first element (the `<p>`) is not bold.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The description is just for the example where they used <p>. You can use :first-child on other elements too, it's not limited to <p>. EDIT: article > p:first-child would do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `article > :first-child` instead. This is called direct descendant selector (AKA [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)):

```css
article > :first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

`article:first-child` targets `article` elements which are the first child of their parent. While `article > :first-child` will target the first child element of the `article`.

Also note that using [descendants selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Descendant_selectors) `article :first-child` rather than the child selector (`article > :first-child`) may cause a trouble since it'll select all the first elements of their parent which are descendants of the `article`.

You might also want to consider `article > p:first-of-type` to target the first `<p>` element which is the child of the `article`.

```css
article > p:first-of-type {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. But I'm wondering where is the difference between article > p:first-child and article > p:first-of-type?

Comment: @Doodlebunch Both are equal in this particular case, but if you add a `<h1>` element before the first paragraph, `p:first-child` won't match the paragraph anymore. Because that paragraph won't be the **first child** of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Use this also:

```
article > :first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

or

```
article p:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

or

```
article p:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answers that helped you the most. Use selector "first-child": 
     article p:first-child
    {
    font-weight:bold;
    }

Answer (score -3):

```
article >: first-child {

font-weight:bold;

}
```

Comment: Please add additional explanations. Code-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: The selector should be `article > :first-child`. Notice the moved colon.